# Where do I find my database host name in Azure?

Tags: wordpress, azure, database-connection, host

I just setup a test domain and uploaded a WordPress to the site via FTP. I visit the site and it take sme through the WP setup config. It asks for db name, user, pass, and also DATABASE HOST. I'm running this off of an Azure setup and have a SQL database. Where can I find the name of this database host? I can only see stuff like server name navigating around the Azure platform. Images would be amazing if you could point it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Setting->Properties page for your database in the portal.  You will see a Server Name field.

Answer (score 0):

Look at setting > Connection Strings
There you will get all the required fields for different kind of connections